# I keep on getting this error in Flutter itemBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

This what shows up in android studio **The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Widget'** and also gives me this reference **package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart**

```
body: new Container(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
                child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: reference,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  reverse: true,
                  sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                  itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                    return new ChatTextController(
                      messageSnapshot: messageSnapshot,
                      animation: animation,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new Divider(height: 1.0),
              new Container(
                decoration:
                new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
                child: _buildTextComposer(),
              ),
              new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                _scaffoldContext = context;
                return new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
              })
            ],
          ),
          decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android
              ? new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border(
                  top: new BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                  )))
              : null,
        )
```

Comment: The reference `package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart` means that your problem has something to do with a `Scaffold`'s constructor.  Are you getting this error on any specific line? Is that message all you get or is there a more detailed error message?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this controller returns a Widget like Container or something and not a dynamic value :

```
ChatTextController(
                      messageSnapshot: messageSnapshot,
                      animation: animation,
);
```

itemBuilder property of ListView always expect a UI widget returned by thier builder function